# Why don't Uno and the other Shienarans go back to Shienar

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

I am referring to the Shienaran that left Shienar with Rand at the beginning of *The Great Hunt* (the second book of the Wheel of Time). They are seen later in the series to just be kind of wandering, staying with Masema because he feeds them, and saying they will likely not see Shienar again before they are old and gray.

Why not just go back? Aren't they still the king's soldiers?

Comment: I'd speculate that Masema has a hold over them somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uno and the other Shienarans broke their oaths to Shienar and swore fealty to the Dragon Reborn after the events at Falme. [(TGH,Ch49)](http://encyclopaedia-wot.org/characters/uz/uno_nomesta.html)

Masema claims to be a Prophet of the Lord Dragon.  I assume that short of following Rand around, following the Prophet (if only self-proclaimed) is probably the next best thing.